# Jython by Keyword-Parameter passing to invoke Java methods

Tags: java, python, class, jython

I have this Java class,

```
public class sample {
    public Integer foo(Integer x){
        return x+5;
    }
}
```

And with Jython I want to call `.foo` while passing "keyword-parameter" to the argument. I ended up with the following Python code,

```
java_file = sample()
kwargs = {'x':3}
print java_file.foo(**kwargs)
```

But this results in an error,

```
print java_file.foo(**kwargs)
TypeError: foo(): takes no keyword arguments
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From this [Jython FAQ](http://www.jython.org/archive/22/userfaq.html):

> **5.3   Supporting *args and **kw in Java methods**
>
> In Jython you can support keyword arguments on Java methods by defining a method like so (the parameters are the important point):
>
> ```
> public PyObject foo(PyObject[] args, String[] keywords);
> ```
>
> The keywords array contains all of the keywords for the keyword-defined arguments. For example, if you called foo with:
>
> ```
> foo(1,2,3,four=4,five=5)
> ```
>
> args would be: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and keywords would be: ['four', 'five'] (an array of 2 elements.)
>
> Additionally, you can use the experimental argument parser org.python.core.ArgParser to deal with mapping these two arrays. Consult the Javadocs (or source) for further details on org.python.core.ArgParser.

In the example above, the sample class might look like this:

```
public class sample {
    public Integer foo(PyObject[] args, String[] keywords) {
        ArgParser argParser = new ArgParser("foo", args, keywords, "x");
        Integer x = argParser.getInt(0);
        return x + 5;
    }
}
```